# Silverstripe subsite module, how to make subsite specific members?

Tags: silverstripe

I wanted to white label silverstripe CMS, i.e. one codebase serves different domains and each domains have their own members, etc. I have asked this question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631017/white-labeling-silverstripe-project). And I was suggested to use Subsite modules.

However this partially solved my problem (I m very new to SilverStripe and official community isn't that active).

I was able to make my custom modules Subsite specific by using following code in my `ModelAdmin`

```
<?php
    class CompaniesAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
        private static $url_segment = 'Companies';

        private static $managed_models = "Company";

        private static $menu_title = 'Companies';

        private static $menu_icon = 'mysite/images/icons/company-icon.png';

        public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null){
            $form = parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);

            $gridField = $form->Fields()->fieldByName($this->sanitiseClassName($this->modelClass));

            if(class_exists('Subsite')){
                $list = $gridField->getList()->filter(array('SubsiteID'=>Subsite::currentSubsiteID()));
                $gridField->setList($list);
            }

            return $form;
        }
    }
?>
```

Everything works as expected, except the `"Security"` Module. My requirement is even membership should be subsite specific. That means members from one subsite is not visible in another subsite, they can't login to another subsite, etc.

I also visited [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507871/silverstripe-subsites-with-independent-user-registrations) by another user. However the suggested solution is not implementable in my scenario.

**My Questions**

1. Is it possible to extend subsite module so that we can have subsite
   specific Members??
2. Can we do without modifying core files?
3. I was able to add hidden field for `SubsiteID` while adding/editing Members and was able to save member with specific `SubsiteID`.

   - How to override Security module, so that I can list/filter subsite specific Members?
   - How to prevent editing of other Subsite's member if someone provides member id in URL querystring?
   - How to prevent member of one subsite login to another subsite?

Any help is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I tried following `injector`, but didn't work, got an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getList() on a non-object in...`

```
<?php


class CustomSecurityAdmin extends SecurityAdmin {

    public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null){
        $form = parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);



        $gridField = $form->Fields()->fieldByName('Member');

        if(class_exists('Subsite')){
            $list = $gridField->getList()->filter(array('SubsiteID'=>Subsite::currentSubsiteID()));
            $gridField->setList($list);
        }

        return $form;
    }
}

?>
```

And in `_config.yml`

```
Injector:
  SecurityAdmin:
    class: CustomSecurityAdmin
```

**UPDATE 2**

My injector for `MemberAuthenticator` class

```
<?php

class CustomMemberAuthenticator extends MemberAuthenticator {

    public static function authenticate($RAW_data, Form $form = null) {
        //add logic before
        //get Subsite ID
        $Subsite = SubsiteDomain::get()->filter('Domain', $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"])->First();
        if($Subsite){
           $SubsiteID = $Subsite->SubsiteID;
        }else{
           $SubsiteID = 0;
        }

        $email = Convert::raw2sql($RAW_data['Email']);

        $member = Member::get()->filter(array(
                                    "Email" => $email,
                                    "SubsiteID" => $SubsiteID
                                ))->First();

        if(!$member){
            if($form) $form->sessionMessage("Invalid User", 'bad');
        }else{
            parent::authenticate($RAW_data,$form);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And `_config.yml`

```
Injector:
  MemberAuthenticator:
    class: CustomMemberAuthenticator
```

But this didn't work the injector is not working at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another hack for this, which flawlessly worked for me.

`/mysite/extensions/CustomLeftAndMain.php`

```
<?php
class CustomLeftAndMain extends Extension {

    public function onAfterInit() {

        self::handleUser();

    }



    public static function handleUser(){
        $currentSubsiteID = Subsite::currentSubsiteID();

        $member =  Member::currentUser();
        $memberBelongsToSubsite =  $member->SubsiteID; 

        if($memberBelongsToSubsite>0 && $currentSubsiteID!=$memberBelongsToSubsite){
            Security::logout(false);
            Controller::curr()->redirect("/Security/login/?_c=1001");
        }
    }


}
```

and in `/mysite/_config.php` add an extension

`LeftAndMain::add_extension('CustomLeftAndMain');`

What above code basically does is, the system lets user login no matter which subsite they belong to. And as long as application is initiated, we'll check whether the logged in user belongs to current website or not (method `handleUser` does it.). 
If user doesnot belong to current site, then they are logged out and then redirected to the login page.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to extend subsite module so that we can have subsite specific Members??

Yes

> Can we do without modifying core files?
>   How to override Security module, so that I can list/filter subsite specific Members?
>   How to prevent member of one subsite login to another subsite?

The two classes you are probably most interested in are `SecurityAdmin` and `MemberAuthenticator`.

All silverstripe core files can be "modified" in some way... of the methods discussed on this video presentation by [StripeCon - Loz Calver - Why you shouldn’t edit SilverStripe core files (and how to do it anyway)](https://vimeo.com/143267909) - I recommend method 3, fork the code and add this custom security to your version of silverstripe.

For `SecurityAdmin` the best option is to simply removing the current `SecurityAdmin` from the menu and adding your own custom class:

in _config.php

```
CMSMenu::remove_menu_item('SecurityAdmin ');
```

> How to prevent editing of other Subsite's member if someone provides member id in URL querystring?

You could determine if the user is allowed to edit the form based on which site they belong to... either in permissions or simply use `updateCMSFields` to remove all fields and a validator to ensure nothing can be submitted that doesn't match your rules.

```
public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {

  if (<not valid user to edit>) $fields = FieldList::create();
  ...
}
```

Here is another question about [how to add a validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492396/silverstripe-conditional-validation) and here are [the docs for that](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/forms/validation/).

Comment: btw WatsMyName I've answered but I was tempted to downvote as you have again asked multiple questions in one place.  It's a lot easier to answer smaller focused questions.  I'm being nice as I've previously had questions downvoted and closed for issues present in your posts.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't get a way work injector for SecurityAdmin. See my update (I m very new in Silverstripe)

Comment: If you are very new please ensure you've gone through all the lessons... http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/ and regarding `SecurityAdmin` please note I advised to remove the existing one, and then subclass it and then it will only show that one.  I'll update the answer to make that much clearer.

Comment: Thanks, will be waiting for the edit.  I have already gone through these video lessons, but is not comprehensive. Good for beginners, but I have to modify existing project, that too in limited period of time.

Comment: What edit are you waiting for? I updated the answer seconds after leaving my comment

Comment: Thanks! I have successfully subclassed the `SecurityAdmin` and removed the menu, Everything worked fine. However  `Injector` for `MemberAuthenticator`, doesn't seem to work at all, Please see my `UPDATE 2`

Comment: ok, I've withdrawn that method (as I hadn't tried it sorry, I assume it is the static that are the problem) so the "always works" method of forking the version of silverstripe and applying your change there is now recommended